# Auto logout/destroy session after Password Change in Django

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I am using **django framework** and I need to auto logout users after password changes (`not password reset via mail`).

I am using django's :"`contrib.auth.views.password_change`" to help me do this,

i.e., I'm not having a separate view and as a result I'm also using `password_change_done` view of Django.

I need to know whether there's any way I can auto logout/destroy sessions after password change while using django's default views?

Comment: Can i ask why? That sounds like it would be really annoying from a usability pov

Comment: I'm working with business infrastructure with a possibility of end user's screen being open to "random" people. I'll try A/B testing and see how users react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

password_change has a post_change_redirect, so you can replace it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def my_password_change(request):
    return password_change(request=request,post_change_redirect=reverse('logout'))
```

Then in your urls.py, set my_password_change as the view that accepts the passowrd change request:

```
url(r'^password_change/done/$',my_password_change,name="my_password_change")
```